# Spring Data JPA bulk identifier generation

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

I have an entity, for which apart from the primary key, an extra unique identifier should be generated:

```kotlin
@Entity
class MyEntity(
   val otherId: String // <- this id is unique as well
) {
    @Id
    @Generated
    var id: UUID // PK
}
```

`otherId` property value is derived from a postgres sequence value, by calling `SELECT nextval(...)` and adding a prefix string. When I do bulk inserts, I have to resort to a custom query defined in my JPA repository for the entity, which retrieves multiple sequence values at once, but I'd like to make this process automatic.

I tried to implement `IdentifierGenerator` interface, but the best I could achieve is a single `SELECT nextval` query was made for each new entity inserted, which is totally unacceptable in my case since batches can consist of hundreds of entities. Digging into the hibernate details didn't give me an answer how to do that either.

Is there a way to generate a number of ids via some callback/hook for multiple entities at once? Or I still have to do everything by hand?

Answer (score 0):

There are hooks to implement this, see this article as an example: https://thorben-janssen.com/custom-sequence-based-idgenerator/

To improve performance, you will have to configure the increment size, which by default is 50. This means that it will increment the sequence by 50 and put these values in a pool from which the values are served for identity generation.